# EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://elastictranscoder.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2012-09-25/jobs

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-elastictranscoder

I have a elastic transcoder job being run in a lambda instance. The instance is python and uses boto3.

When the lambda runs I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://elastictranscoder.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2012-09-25/jobs"
```

The elastictranscoder job via boto3 is as follows:

```
client = boto3.client('elastictranscoder', region_name='us-east-2')
        client.create_job(
            PipelineId='kirke-audio',
            Input={
                "Key": rawbucketkey,
            },
            Output={
                "Key": rawbucketkey + '.mp3',
                "PresetId": "1351620000001-300030"
            },
            UserMetadata={
                "content-type": contentype,
                "userid": userid,
                "contentpostid": contentpostid,
                "rawbucketkey": rawbucketkey
            }
```

I have been searching but I do not know why this is happening.

The Lambda function has full aws elastictranscoder IAM permissions

Comment: Are you launching the lambda in a VPC?  Are you launching in the right region?

Comment: I dont think it is in a vpc. And it is in ohio not virgina a supported region.